# calculating an exponential distribution problem

Tags: probability, exponential-function

I am given this fairly-easy question, yet I cannot find a reasonable solution.

> The time it takes to stare at an object is approx. 20ms. The waiting
>   time distribution is exponential:
>
> $$f(x)= \lambda e^{-\lambda x} ; F(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$$
>
> **1)** Calculate the probability that you are able to stare at an object in the first 100ms after opening your eyes.
>   **2)** Calculate the probability of staring a three different objects in the first 900ms after opening your eyes.

I have tried to answer the first question in this way:
$$F(x)=F(100ms=\frac{1}{10}s)=1-e^{-(\frac{1}{10}*\frac{2}{100})*1}$$
where $(\frac{1}{10}*\frac{2}{100})$ is $\lambda$ and x is 1, as "starting one object".

Similarly, the second answer would be:
$$F(x)=F(900ms=\frac{9}{10}s)=1-e^{-(\frac{9}{10}*\frac{2}{100})*3}$$
but I'm far from saying that I'm sure of what I've done.

I am aware that this might be a huge duplicate question, but I haven't been able to find a similar question, I'm sorry if I've done something wrong.

Comment: On the first part, I think that although your answer seems correct the interpretation is not. As I understand you want to calculate $F(0.1)=P(\text{waiting time}\leq 0.1)= 1- e^{-50* 0.1}$ (here $\lambda $ is the inverse of the mean, notice that the problem says that "approximately the time needed to see an object is 20ms").

Comment: On the second case, are the events independent?

Comment: I'm sorry, I know it's unclear but it's hard to translate it. Basically, in the first case we want to calculate the probability to see an object in the first 100ms after opening the eyes. On average, perceiving an object takes 20ms. Therefore the question. Hope it's clear. And yes, the events **are independent**.